# How can I control the loading of images to a sprite in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, sprite

How can I control the loading of images to a sprite
I have a vector where I have the name of the image I want to load but to perform the cycle where I used the contentLoaderInfo With the even init property It loads the random images, they are not loaded in the order they are in the array.
I cannot get the images to be added to the stage in the order that the arrangement is I have tried with Even.init Even.complete and I cannot get the result that I wish otherwise how could I do it

```
var lista_nombresPises:Array = new Array("ar.png","br.png","ch.png","co.png","it.png","ja.png","mx.png","pa.png","sp.png","US.png");
var nombresPaises_sprites:Array = [];
for(i=0;i<lista_nombresPises.length;i++){
    nombresPaises_sprites.push(new Sprite);
    nombresPaises_sprites[i].name = "pais"+(i+1);//Le asignamos el nombre
    direc= new URLRequest("Palabras/Paises/"+lista_nombresPises[i]);//Fue creado en el login
    var loadPaises:Loader = new Loader();
    loadPaises.load(direc);
    loadPaises.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT,cargaImagenBandera);
}
var indi = 0;
var posy = 118;
function cargaImagenBandera(eve:Event):void{
    nombresPaises_sprites[indi].addChild(eve.target.content);
    nombresPaises_sprites[indi].x = 65;
    nombresPaises_sprites[indi].y = posy;
    posy=posy+60;
    addChild(nombresPaises_sprites[indi]);
    indi++;
}

//Cargamos las Banderas de los paises
var lista_Banderas:Array = new Array("banAr.png","banBr.png","banCh.png","banCo.png","banIt.png","banJa.png","banMx.png","banPa.png","banSp.png","banUs.png");
var banderas_sprites:Array = [];
for(i = 0; i<lista_Banderas.length;i++){
    var direcBandera:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Palabras/Paises/Banderas/"+lista_Banderas[i]);
    banderas_sprites.push(new Sprite);
    var loaderBandera:Loader = new Loader();
    loaderBandera.load(direcBandera);
    loaderBandera.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT,cargarBanderas);
}
```

**If it was not understood correctly what I am trying to do is that the images are always loaded in a certain sequence. For example, the image with the name img1 should always be loaded first. managed to get them loaded in a sequence like the one in the array**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading is an asynchronous operation in AS3. That means if you bulk request loading a handful of files, they will not necessarily finish loading in the very same order.

However, you don't even need to wait for them to finish loading, that is if you know the image sizes, don't intend to smartly auto-resize the line, don't intend to handle errors, and so on. You can arrange them in advance and then set them loading. The external content will display when it is loaded and available.

```
var baseURL:String = "Palabras/Paises/";
var aList:Array = [
    "ar.png","br.png","ch.png","co.png","it.png",
    "ja.png","mx.png","pa.png","sp.png","US.png"
];

for (var i:int = 0; i < aList.length; i++)
{
    // Create required objects.
    var aRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest;
    var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;
    var aWrap:Sprite = new Sprite;

    // Form a proper URL.
    aRequest.url = baseURL + aList[i];

    // Arrange the (currently) empty container
    // to its designated position.
    aLoadex.x = 65;
    aLoader.y = 118 + 60 * i;

    // Start loading the external resource.
    aLoader.load(aRequest);

    // Loader subclasses DisplayObject and can be added
    // to the stage just as any other. It will display the
    // content it loads when the content is available.
    aWrap.addChild(aLoader);
    addChild(aWrap);

    // Replace the filename on the list with the
    // corresponding Loader instance, if you need them
    // in the future for anything.
    aList[i] = aWrap;
}
```

Comment: Still, listening for `EVent.COMPLETE` is desirable in this scenario. For example, should there be a desire to label a button with loaded image, one first would need to wait until the loading would be finished. This approach shows only one part of the puzzle, I think it needs to show two.

Comment: the problem would be that I cannot add it to the sprite, because I need the user to interact with the image

Comment: @RodrigoGutierrez I don't see a problem here. You can use an additional proxy **Sprite**, so the hierarchy is "common container → proxy **Sprite** → **Loader** instance → loaded image". I updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: @Vesper You're absolutely right, but as you can see OP got lost in a pretty trivial logic and even if I devise a code that would track back from **LoaderInfo** instances to **Loader** instances and their indices (via **Dictionary** or **Array** search) or suggest an AS3 class approach with components able to handle image loading, I think it will only make more confusion instead of clarifying things up. Thus I aimed to create as simpler working idea as possible. Still, I encourage you to post a better answer where things get explained.